# How to validate that user is not able to enter any data in the given field using selenium java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I want to validate that field is not editable.
Code I am trying is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@comp-id='1494']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@comp-id='1494']")).sendKeys("PleaseCHECK");
```

But this is not working as it successfully pass this and according to my TC this is incorrect

div of above element (which is not editable) looks like:

```
<div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" comp-id="1534" col-id="FGA_PROCESSOR" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-value ag-cell-no-focus" style="width: 97px; left: 1864px; "></div>
```

div of editable field looks like:

```
<div tabindex="-1" role="gridcell" comp-id="1532" col-id="fgaConfigDescription" class="ag-cell ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-value ag-cell-focus ag-cell-inline-editing ag-column-hover" style="width: 175px; left: 1581px; "><input class="ag-cell-edit-input" type="text"></div>
```

Only difference between editable and non editable fields is on INPUT tag.

I just need to make sure that the field is not editable and doesn't accept any text/data

Comment: When you say "it passes" you mean that the test ends green or that the "PleaseCHECK" text is placed on the input? If you do a getText after the sendKeys it returns the inputted text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate this by using try and catch also,
**look at this:**

```
public static boolean isElementPresent(By by)
    {
        try{            
            driver.findElement(by);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Now use this method in your test class-**

```
By value1= By.xpath(".//div[@comp-id='1534']/input");
By value2= By.xpath(".//div[@comp-id='1534']");

driver.findElement(value2).click();
Assert.assertEquals(isElementPresent(value1), false, "Field is editable");
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your scenario, If you validate that INPUT tag is not available, then you could identify text field is not editable.

Try this piece of code:

```
    List lstElmnt=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@comp-id='1494']/input")); 
     if(lstElmnt.size()<=0)
     { 
       System.out.println("Text field is not editable"); 
     } 
    else 
     { 
        Assert.fail("Text field is editable"); 
     }
```

Comment: INPUT tag is only visible when you click in that field. @user40540

Answer (score 0):

```
`//Fist click on an element
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@comp-id='1494']")).click();
//Then validate Input tag
List <WebElement> lstElmnt=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@comp-id='1494']/input")); if(lstElmnt.size()<=0){
 System.out.println("Text field is not editable"); }
else { Assert.fail("Text field is editable"); }`
```

Answer (score -1):

You could specifically check for the not-inline-editing part of the Class:

```java
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[comp-id='1494'][class^='cell-not-inline-editing']"));
```

Above should check the comp-id entry also has a class that contains (denoted by ^=) 'cell-not-inline-editing'.

Comment: But this assumes that the CSS rule behaves correct; one can simply write an empty CSS class - which still allows editing.